# Eisenstein and Quadratic Reciprocity as a consequence of Artin Reciprocity, and Composition of Reciprocity Laws

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

**Question 1**: I've heard that **Eisenstein** and **Quadratic** Reciprocity can be derived from the **Artin** Reciprocity by applying it to **certain field extensions**. But I haven't seen on any reference an explicit description of this, and I am here asking for one.

**Question 2**: I have seen **quartic, octic, and sextic reciprocity laws**. They look just like by applying some kind of power reciprocity in fields satisfying another power reciprocity law. So is there a general procedure to construct reciprocity of **arbitrary powers** based on composition of reciprocity of degree 2 and odd primes (Since their product generate the natural numbers)? If not, what is the obstruction?

Comment: For a derivation of cubic reciprocity from Artin reciprocity, see Theorem 2.3.5 (p. 63) of Noah Snyder's senior thesis on Artin L-functions, which is currently available from his Columbia Univ. webpage.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To derive quadratic reciprocity from Artin reciprocity, consider the field extensions $$\mathbb{Q} \subset F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p^*}) \subset K=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$$ where $p$ is a prime $\ne 2$, $\zeta$ is a primitive $p$th root of unity, and $p^* = (-1)^{(p-1)/2} p$.

(To see that $F$ is contained in $K$, look up Gauss sums.)

Let $q$ be another prime, $q \ne p, q \ne 2$.  We know that $p^*$ is a square mod $q$ iff $q$ splits in $F$ iff the Artin symbol of $q$ in $F/\mathbb{Q}$ is trivial.  (All Galois groups considered here are abelian, so the Artin map depends only on the base prime $q$ and not on any particular prime in the upper field.)

The Artin symbol of $K/\mathbb{Q}$ over the prime $q$ is the element $\sigma_q: \zeta \mapsto \zeta^q$ in the Galois group of $K/\mathbb{Q}$.

But Artin($F/\mathbb{Q}$) is the restriction of Artin($K/\mathbb{Q}$) to $F$, so Artin($F/\mathbb{Q}$) is trivial iff $\sigma_q$ is in the kernel of this restriction map.  Both Galois groups are cyclic, and so this restriction map is the unique nontrivial homomorphism from $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ to $\{\pm 1\}$.  It is easy to check that $\sigma_q$ will be in the kernel of the restriction map iff $q$ is a square mod $p$.

Conclusion: $p^*$ is a square mod $q$ iff $q$ is a square mod $p$.  This is quadratic reciprocity.

For other reciprocity laws, you'll have to choose the field $F$ differently.  For example, for cubic reciprocity, choose $F$ to be the unique degree 3 extension in $K/\mathbb{Q}$.  (Of course, this only exists if $p \equiv 1$ (mod 3), but if that condition fails then cubic reciprocity is not very interesting: everything will be a cube mod $p$.)  Things get more complicated because the analog of the step "$p^*$ is a square mod $q$ iff $q$ splits in $F$" is not as simple.  But it's the same idea.

Edit: This last paragraph is not quite correct.  The proper extensions to consider for cubic reciprocity is $L \subset L(p^{1/3})$ where $L = \mathbb{Q}(\omega)$, $\omega$ a primitive cube root of unity.  The Artin conductor of this extension is a divisor of $3p$, and given a prime $q \equiv 1$ (mod 3) in $L$ (relatively prime to $3p$), the image of the ideal $(q)$ given by Artin reciprocity is essentially the unique nontrivial map from the cyclic group $(O_L / q)^{\times}$ to the cyclic group Gal($L(p^{1/3})/L$) of order 3.  For details, see the senior thesis of Noah Snyder referenced by KCd in the comments above.  For general $n$th power reciprocity, use $L \subset L(p^{1/n})$ where $L$ is the cyclotomic field generated by a primitive $n$th root of unity.

Comment: How to determine the Artin symbol of $K/Q$ over the prime $q$?

Comment: By definition, the Artin symbol of an unramified prime $\mathfrak{q}$ (in $K$) over a prime $q$ (in $\mathbb{Q}$) is the unique automorphism $\sigma \in$ Gal($K/\mathbb{Q}$) such that $\sigma(x) \equiv x^q$ (mod $\mathfrak{q}$) for all $x \in K$.  The map $\sigma_q$ above satisfies this property.

Comment: A small remark: if you are already going to use all this algebraic number theory for a proof of quadratic reciprocity, I think it is cleaner to argue that $F\subset K$ by observing that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ must contain a unique quadratic subfield that ramifies only over $p$, hence is of the form $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ where $d\equiv 1\bmod 4$ and has only the prime $p$ as prime divisor. This forces $d=p^{*}$.

Answer (score 1):

For a nice simple example use the extension $\mathbb{Q}(i)/\mathbb{Q}$.

Notice that for an odd prime $p$ (i.e. unramified) the Frobenius element of $p$ relative to this extension is the identity if and only if $p\equiv 1 \bmod 4$.

When showing this algebraically you find that:

Frob$_p(a+ib) \equiv a + (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}bi \bmod \mathfrak{p}$

However, by Eulers criterion the RHS is congruent to $a + \left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)bi\bmod \mathfrak{p}$.

So really the Frobenius element of $p$ here encodes the value of the Legendre symbol $\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)$.

Thus $\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right) = 1$ if and only if Frob$_p$ is the identity, which is equivalent to $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$.

This gives one of the supplementary laws. The rest of quadratic reciprocity comes from changing the above extension to something similar (as shown by the other replies).

Comment: $@fretty$ if you don't mind, could you explain  how $Frob_{p}(a+ib)\equiv a+(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}bi\pmod{\mathfrak{p}}$    , is it by definition? and does $\frak{p}$ lies above  $p$. if so what happens for  $Q(\sqrt{-3})/Q$

Comment: Yes, $\mathfrak{p}$ lies above $p$ and so when working mod $\mathfrak{p}$ (i.e. in the residue field) you will be working in characteristic $p$. By definition Frob$_p (a+ib) \equiv (a+ib)^{p} \bmod \mathfrak{p}$. You get what I write from this...

Comment: If you do it for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})/\mathbb{Q}$ you will find the Legendre symbol $\left(\frac{-3}{p}\right)$ hidden in there for unramified $p$. I gather the workings will not be as nice. You should read D.Cox's book "Primes of the form $x^2 + ny^2$", there is a nice section on Frobenius elements, class field theory, Artin reciprocity and how the weak/strong reciprocity laws follow from it (it is these ones that explicitly give you quadratic, cubic, quartic, Eisenstein reciprocity laws plus many others).

Comment: Thanks Fretty, Thank you very much

Comment: You should try the calculations for this extension by yourself...it is not too hard. The hard bit is in understanding the general proof of quadratic reciprocity above.

Comment: The real thing that is going on here is that for any abelian extension if you use any representation $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q}) \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ then there will be a corresponding mod $N$ Dirichlet character for some $N$ that agrees with it on the level of primes and Frobenius elements. In the case of quadratic extensions if we define the representation given by $\text{id}\mapsto 1$ and $\text{conj} \mapsto -1$ then the corresponding Dirichlet character agreeing with Frob$_p$ is the Legendre symbol $\left(\frac{\Delta}{p}\right)$ where $\Delta$ is the discriminant of the extension.

Comment: Let $x\in K=Q(\sqrt{d})$ and $Frob_{p}(x)\equiv x\pmod{\mathfrak{p}}$ such that $p$ splits completely in $Q(\sqrt{d})$, Then the Artin symbol of $p$ is trivial right?

Comment: The artin symbol is defined on elements of the ring of integers of the number field in question. It is a general fact that if prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $\mathcal{O}_K$ is unramified in an abelian extension $L/K$ then the Frobenius element is trivial if and only if $\mathfrak{p}$ splits completely in $L$.

Comment: thanks @fretty, also, if $p=\mathfrak{p1}\mathfrak{p2}$ in $K$, such that, $x\equiv 1\pmod{p}$,  and $Frob_p(x)>0$ then is it true that, $x\equiv 1\pmod{\mathfrak{p1}}$ and $x\equiv 1\pmod{\mathfrak{p2}}$, i.e, the corresponding Artin symbols over $\mathfrak{p1}$  and  $\mathfrak{p1}$ are trivial

Comment: What does Frob$_p(x)>0$ mean? It makes no sense in general fields.

Comment: I'm sorry, the corresponding automorphism, $\sigma_p(x)$

Comment: No my point is there is not necessarily an ordering on a number field...would you say $i>0$?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11248/discussion-between-sushma-palimar-and-fretty)

Comment: hi, finally 1 question:Is the below true
$Frob_{7} (2+\sqrt{2})\equiv 2+\sqrt{2} \pmod{-1+2\sqrt{2}}$ is identity, hence the Artin symbol is trivial is right?

Comment: Luckily, yes...but in general it takes more than one element to determine the Artin symbol. It is only because you are in a quadratic extension that it is defined completely by its action on $\sqrt{2}$.