# Artin Reciprocity $\implies$ Cubic Reciprocity

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, cubic-reciprocity

I'm trying to understand the proof of cubic reciprocity from Artin reciprocity as outlined in [this well-known previous math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265392/eisenstein-and-quadratic-reciprocity-as-a-consequence-of-artin-reciprocity-and) and [the link KCd mentions there](http://math.columbia.edu/~nsnyder/thesismain.pdf). However, there's one final step that I can't get to work. **I suspect that the proofs linked above are in fact incomplete but I'd like to confirm that I'm not missing something.** (Reason: if Artin alone worked, I think Cox would have done it in his book $x^2+ny^2$, which he conspicuously does not.)

So let me write out what I've figured out so far.
Let $K = \mathbb Q(\sqrt{-3})$, and let $\pi$ be a primary prime in $K$.
(For me, primary means $\pi \equiv 1 \pmod 3$.) We want to prove

**Cubic Reciprocity**: If $\theta$ is a primary prime in $K$ distinct from $\pi$ then
$$\left( \frac{\pi}{\theta} \right)_3 = \left( \frac{\theta}{\pi} \right)_3.$$

Now the proof proceeds as follows.
The main idea is to consider the diagram
[image]
Here, the top row is the Artin symbol,
followed by the ``evaluation'' map
$$ \text{ev }_\pi : \sigma \mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{\pi}} \sigma(\sqrt[3]{\pi}) $$
so that the composition yields the cubic Legendre symbol (top row).
Then Artin reciprocity implies that the Artin map is surjective and
factors through $I_K(3\pi)/P_K(3\pi)$,
which is isomorphic to $\left( \mathcal O_K/\pi \right)^\times$
by taking any prime ideal and sending it to its primary generator
(this is the map in the bottom row).
Finally, the rightmost arrow
$\left( \mathcal O_K/\pi \right)^\times \to \{1, \omega, \omega^2\}$
is surjective from the rest of the diagram.

Now the claim I don't believe is that this implies the rightmost arrow
is $\left( \frac{\bullet}{\pi} \right)_3$, which would imply cubic reciprocity.
The argument is that the kernel of the rightmost arrow is an index three
subgroup of $(\mathcal O_K/\pi)^\times$,
hence it consists of the cubes in $(\mathcal O_K/\pi)^\times$.
This means that
$$
\left( \frac{\theta}{\pi} \right) = 1
\implies \left( \frac{\pi}{\theta} \right) = 1.
$$
However, it doesn't seem to work for the other values,
for the reason that there are in fact *two* different
nontrivial homomorphisms $(\mathcal O_K/\pi)^\times \to \{1, \omega, \omega^2\}$,
namely
$\left( \frac{\bullet}{\pi} \right)_3$
and $\left( \frac{\bullet}{\pi} \right)_3^{-1}$.
(This is different from the quadratic case, in which there was only one.)
In other words, from this we can only conclude that for a fixed $\pi$, either
$$
\left( \frac{\theta}{\pi} \right)_3 = \left( \frac{\pi}{\theta} \right)_3
\quad\text{ or }\quad
\left( \frac{\theta}{\pi} \right)_3 = \left( \frac{\pi}{\theta} \right)_3^{-1}
\qquad \forall \theta \equiv 1 \pmod 3.
$$

**Question: how do you prove that we are in the former case and not the latter?**
One idea I had was to pick a convenient value of $\theta$ and just check it directly,
but I haven't been able to find a way to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to mark this as answered, I re-posted this question on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/234358/artin-reciprocity-implies-cubic-reciprocity) and got a fantastic answer from David Speyer there.