# Proof of quadratic reciprocity from Artin reciprocity

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, quadratic-reciprocity

I just read the proof of the quadratic reciprocity from the Artin reciprocity here [Eisenstein and Quadratic Reciprocity as a consequence of Artin Reciprocity, and Composition of Reciprocity Laws](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265392/eisenstein-and-quadratic-reciprocity-as-a-consequence-of-artin-reciprocity-and) given by Ted. It looks great but I cannot see where Artin reciprocity shows up in the proof. Probably I am missing something silly there. Can anyone remind me where it is used?

Comment: $p^*$ is a square mod $q$ iff $q$ splits in $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p^*})$ iff the Frobenius $\sigma$ at $q$ of $C=\mathbb{Q}(\mu_p)$ is in $Gal(C/K)$. Now $Gal(C/\mathbb{Q})$ is cyclic and $Gal(C/K)$ has index two, so $Gal(C/K)=2Gal(C/\mathbb{Q})$. Thus $p^*$ is a square mod $q$ iff $\sigma$ is a square in $Gal(C/\mathbb{Q})$. But $Gal(C/\mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$ under an isomorphism mapping $\sigma$ to $q$, so $p^*$ is a square mod $q$ iff $q$ is a square in $\mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$, QED. No Artin reciprocity here, just classical algebraic number theory.

Comment: You might also want to look at Theorems 8.11 and 8.12 of [Cox](https://www.amazon.com/Primes-Form-Multiplication-Solutions-Publishing/dp/1470470284)

Answer (score 1):

See Example 6.5 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/cfthistory.pdf).  Artin reciprocity is used to interpret the Legendre symbol $(\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z)^\times \to \{\pm 1\}$ for an odd prime $p$ as the Artin map from a certain generalized ideal class group of $\mathbf Q$ to the Galois group of a certain quadratic extension of $\mathbf Q$.